# Soft keyboard not closing when dialog is cancelled

Tags: android-studio, android-edittext, android-dialog

In my app i have a dialog where the user should enter some text in an edittext. But when I tap outside of the dialog to close the dialog, the dialog closes but the soft keyboard which popped up because i clicked on the edittext stays. It's very weird: when I set windowsoftinputmode to stateAlwaysHidden,the keyboard gets a bit transparent but it doesn't close. I only have this problem in portrait, In landscape it doesn't happen but that could be because the softkeyboard fills the whole screen. I also cant click on the keys of the keyboard it doesn't react. I already tried to set the windowsoftinputmode to different values and I set a oncancellistener on my dialo g which should close the softkeyboard but it doesn't. It's seems to me as a bug.

The code of my dialog

````
public void create(View view) {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_SWIPE_TO_DISMISS);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialoglayout);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

                View view = getCurrentFocus();

                if (view == null) {
                    view = new View(getBaseContext());
                }
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        });
        editText = dialog.findViewById(R.id.levelname);
        editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    name = editText.getText().toString();
                    callables.totaloverwriteFile(name,getApplicationContext(),"newlevelname");
                    getApplicationContext().startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CreatorActivity.class));
                    return true;
                }
        return true;
            }
        });


    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try building InputMethodManager from context, something like this (kotlin)

```
    val inputMethodManager = context?.getSystemService<InputMethodManager>()
    inputMethodManager?.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken,0)
```

Comment: i the problem just disappeared i was trying your answer but it didn't work. When i put it back to my original code with which i had the problem and ran it .Out of nowhere I didn't have the problem ,I checked the code and it's completely the same. But the problem is fixed so i'm happy (: